# MBR to GPT without data loss without any tools

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I was installing Ubantu on dual boot with Windows 10 and my disk type was set to MBR. 
3 primary partitions and 1 extended. And one of the drive was empty i kept this purposely i thought i could use for ubantu but While installing ubantu it asked me for efi drive So I extend from this empty drive to create 500 MB partition for efi and another partition of 25GB for root.but installation failed statinng unable to create partition and it took almost 6 hours with no further progress that's when i shut down the laptop to restart.

When I restarted it thrown an error *operating system was not found*.
 Searching online I got that I messed up with MBR table and have to fix it.

So I tried to repair windows with troubleshooting using Diskpart and ran the bootsec commands but some commands were not working.
Then I ran boot tests for hard-disk status all of which passed successfully.So thought instead of repairing windows should reinstall it and started reinstalling windows but when  tried to choose the drive to install windows it threw error as *Windows can not be installed on this drive ,this drive contains MBR table*

Thought formatting the drives might help so I formatted 3 drives 1. with old Windows installation 2. EFI drive 3.root drive and again tried to reinstall again it gave same error.
So I thought may be I should recover MBR table troubleshooting using Diskpart but now it stated *no windows installation found* as had formatted the drive on which Windows was installed.
Again I searched online it gave me commands for converting disk from MBR to GPT but while using these commands in diskpart when I will use **clear command** I will lose all the data. 
I don't want to lose the data as its not backedup.
So my question is ia there any way to convert MBR to GPT without losing the data. Or there are any ways of recovering MBR so that my windows will automatically get detect while booting.Also if there is some way to still go ahead and install ubantu and access this data from Ubuntu? Or there are any other ways to do the respective installations I am stuck with no end and by no means I can afford to lose the data.

PS: I am in the middle of both installations and can not use any tools for backup.
some things might be silly as this was my 1st try of installing both.Help much appreciated.

Comment: If you can shut that computer off, then do so, remove the drive and attach it to another computer as a secondary drive, and create an image of the drive. You really need a backup because you're at a point where it's easy mess up the drive and loose the data. You could also use the same computer by first installing another OS on another drive, and use the problematic drive then as a secondary drive (you should be able to select that in the BIOS).

Comment: @Daniel can i install ubuntu successfully and then access the other partitions? If i'm not wrong by another drive u mean another partition on disk or u mean i need another hard disk?

Comment: I mean another hard disk, just to be on the safe side. You could (if you can do it without corrupting any data) do it on the existing drive, but then you really need to know what you're doing. Maybe wait for some further help, for an answer, before proceeding. But what I would do is to first make a complete image of the entire HDD on another system (because I do have another one available).

Comment: I'd also suggest verification of the imaging to make sure (by checksum or other method) that the image on drive A matches in detail the image on drive B.